# Reactjs - array/iterator key

Tags: reactjs, key

I've got the following error:

> warning.js?0260:45Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should
>   have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Tabs`.

```
  render() {

    const { tabs } = this.props;
    const { active } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ButtonToolbar>
          {tabs.map(listValue =>
            <Button  onClick={() => this.handleClick(listValue)}>
              {listValue}
            </Button>
          )}
        </ButtonToolbar>

        // Display the chosen tab
        {this.showTab(active)}



      </div>
    );
```

Where would I add the id property in this case. I've tried:

```
<ButtonToolbar>
              {tabs.map(listValue =>
                <Button key={listValue.id}  onClick={() => this.handleClick(listValue)}>
                  {listValue}
                </Button>
              )}
            </ButtonToolbar>
```

But it does not get rid of the error. Please advise

Comment: if you console.log(listValue.id) are they all unique?

Comment: You could also do `tabs.map((listValue, index) =>
                <Button key={listValue.id + index}  onClick={() => this.handleClick(listValue)}>
                  {listValue}
                </Button>
              )}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map`'s iterator for this:

```
<ButtonToolbar>
  {tabs.map((listValue, key) =>
    <Button              ^--- here
      key={key}   <--- and here.
      onClick={() => this.handleClick(listValue)}
    >
      {listValue}
    </Button>)
  }
</ButtonToolbar>
```

#### Reference

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)